# thunderbirds scrolls back to a selected folder

Tags: windows, thunderbird

I have just installed Thunderbird on Windows and added 2 imap accounts.

Those 2 imap accounts contains a lot of folders, so there is a scrollbar in the menu to the left. So far so god.

But if I click on a folder(which selects it), and then scroll up/down so the selected folder scrolls out of the current view, thunderbird scrolls the view back so the selected folder is visible again. Is there anyway to avoid this feature/bug?

Or is there at least a way to unselect a folder, so I can scroll away from it.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but on the Linux version I can click on a folder to select it and then control click on it to unselect it. BTW, I have a lot of folders and I do not see this problem. I would see something like it if I selected the folder, scrolled the folder list, and then clicked on a message in the message pane. This correct behavior might look like a bug if I wasn't paying attention. Just scrolling the folder list does not affect the message pane (for good reasons).